# C - Conflicting types for 'file' error

Tags: c, file, types

When I try to compile my C program, I get the following error:

```
file.c:16:1: error: conflicting types for 'file'
```

concerning this code:

```
char *filename = "dictionary.txt";
FILE *file;
file = fopen(filename, "a+");
```

I have used the article as a reference:
[C File I/O and Binary File I/O](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)

Any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Edit:
here is the full code
http://pastebin.com/3iMmGzfk

Comment: Is there anything else named `file`... another variable, a function name, etc?

Comment: i just searched for 'file' and there is no other variable or function with the same name.

Comment: Change `FILE *file` to `FILE *fp` and see what happens... Also change all references to `file`, of course...

Comment: Could you please put entire code listing? It has more than 17 lines indeed.

Comment: Adding some boilerplate around your code, compiling and running it works just fine here.

Answer (score 1):

With this code I get the same  `error: conflicting types for ‘file’`. Note the definition of file twice in the same scope.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int file = 0;

    char *filename = "dictionary.txt";
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "a+");

    return 0;
}
```

Making sure there is not another variable named file in the same scope should solve the problem.

For example I don't get a compiler error with this version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int file = 0;

    {
        char *filename = "dictionary.txt";
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(filename, "a+");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The article you link to actually uses `fp` for the `FILE *` variable name, but if your own code doesn't elsewhere define a `file`, then somewhere a header file you are directly or indirectly using is defining something called `file`. Without knowing your platform, it's hard to say which header file would be defining a `file`.